# Xcode Cocos2d error

Tags: ios

I'm observing a problem in the implementation of Google admob framework within my project, which is one of these files giving me this following error "Duplicate interface definition for class GADInterstitial", the problem is that I only have one file of this one, I didn't insert #include anywhere but always #import, I tried to delete DerivedData files and I also changed the bundle name to the project but no one of these attempts has solved the error, nevertheless I have another same project (with a different name) with same classes, settings, etc... and there works perfectly! So I wanted to know, is it possible that the Google framework could go in conflict between the two different projects? In that case what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

try adding GADInterstitial class files in your second project.

got to project -> target -> build phases and check for copy bundle resources . check that there is no duplicate files.

If you have renamed any header file then do this

1)Clean project(s)
2)Delete the "Derived Data" (Organizer > Projects tab, select the project and click Delete)
3)Restart Xcode
4)Build

hope this help you.

Comment: of course I have it in the second project, otherwise i can't implement the advertisement